# Expanding object/feature pixel area

Tags: matlab, image-processing, aggregate, boundary

Which method is commonly used to evaluate the remaining 'boundary' pixels after an initial segmentation (based on thresholds)?

I thought about classification based on a standard deviation from the threshold values but I don't know if that is common practice in image analysis. This would be a region growing method but based on the answer on this question ( http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/53351-how-can-i-segment-a-color-image-with-region-growing ) it is not sensible to use the region growing algorithm. Someone suggested `imdilate`. This method seems arbitrary, useful when enhancing images for aesthetic purpose or to enhance the visibility. For my problem the assigning of the pixels has to be correct because I have to do measurements on these extracted objects/features and a few pixels make a huge difference.

What I was looking for :

1. To collect my boundary pixels of the BW image from the first segmentation (which I found : http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html)
2. A decision rule (nearest neighbor ?) to classify those boundary pixels. It would be helpful if there were multiple methods to do this, because it makes a relative accuracy check of the classification possible.

I would really appreciate the input/advice from someone with more experience in this area to point me to the right direction (functions, tutorials etc…)

Thank you !

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean: Did you do a segmentation, and now want to refine the segmented regions by adding or removing some pixels at the boundary?

Comment: @Jonas : Yes, I did a segmentation based on rgb and lab color space channels (not combined, two separate approaches). I want to reevaluate the pixels at the boarders (or if computationally not to slow all the pixels assigned a 0) of the result of this segmentation (the pixels assigned a 1) to add pixels (not remove). I want this evaluation to be based on the color channel values (a deviation from these values) of the pixels extracted from the initial segmentation.

Answer (score 0):

What will work for you depends very much on the images you have. This is no one-size-fits-all algorithm.

First, you need to answer the question: Given a pixel close to a segmented feature, what would make you believe that this pixel belongs to the feature? Also: what is "close"?

The answer to the second question determines your search area. Here, `imdilate` is useful to identify candidate pixels (i.e. you dilate your feature, subtract the feature, and you are left with a ring of candidate pixels around each feature). If you test on all pixels, the risk is not so much that it could take forever, but that for some images, your region growing mechanism expands to the entire image.

The answer to the first question determines what algorithm you'll use. Do you look for a gradient, i.e. "if pixel p is closer in intensity to the adjacent feature than to most of its neighbors, then I take it"? Do you look for texture? Do you look for a local threshold (hysteresis thresholding)? The answer, again, depends very much on the images you are segmenting. Make sure you test on a large set of images, because what may look good on one image may totally fail on a different one.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how I have to approach it. I will clarrify the problem. I want to extract and measure fruits (I started with the red, the green I will do later because this will be more difficult) on a green (vegetation) background. I think for the red fruit the best approach is looking for a gradient. For the green fruit the texture approach. I am not familiar with hysteresis thresholding.

Comment: Hysteresis thresholding is the idea that you have a high threshold (i.e. "these pixels are for sure part of the object") and a low threshold (i.e. "these pixels are probably part of the object"). Then, you take all pixels passing the high threshold, and all pixels passing the low threshold in a region adjacent to one that is part of the high threshold.